# How do I find index in a List using a subList of that list?

Tags: java, list, collections, sublist

I have a list and I'm trying to write a function(just for the practice) that finds an index of a specified value from that list , But using a subList of that list.
When i find index in the subList , the index is only for that subList . Is there any way to find the actual index from the main list but using the subList ?

hope i made myself clear

- thanks

Comment: subList start index + index of specified value in sublist

Comment: Why do you want to find index of sublist ? Can you explain usecase ?

Comment: you can loop trough list and search for identity

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer is why would you want to do that anyway. And the even longer answer is just use `List.indexOf`.

Comment: insert some of the `code` -work you have done so far

Comment: Actually, you can only access index of sub list through main list. That means you already know what is the index of main list. are not you?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a clasical for, example:

```
for(int i=0; i<originalList.size(); i++){
//capture i value
 for(int j=0; i<subList.size(); j++){
 //if you find return i value;

}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find index of sublist with `java.util.Collections.indexOfSubList(List<?> source, List<?> target)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public class SublistIterator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("A"); add("B");
            add("C"); add("D");
            add("E"); add("F");
            add("G"); add("H");
            add("I"); add("J");
        }};

        int index = 0;
        int start = 2;
        int end = list.size() - 2;
        for(String item :  list.subList(start, end)){
            if("E".equals(item)){
                System.out.println("Found at index : " + index);
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

}
```